# Single word for something that is "not yet a fact" but very close?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes something that is not yet a scientifically proven fact, but people intuitively think to be true. The word is not "hypothesis" as I'm not describing The Scientific Method. Also hypothesis implies something that is potentially disprovable. I'm looking for a stronger term. Is there such a word or a phrase?

EDIT:
Here is an example:
"Hard work does not guarantee success".
**People think (or know) this to be true even though it's not yet scientifically provable or disprovable**. It's a general truth, not a hypothesis or a theory.

Comment: 1. Single word requests require an example phrase. 2. Have you tried looking up "hypothesis" in a thesaurus? Were any of the words any good? Please include your research. 3. Something which people "think is true" is a "belief". I suspect this isn't the word you're looking for, but it may also be worth trying in a thesaurus.

Comment: In my understanding, anything "people intuitively think to be true" usually turns out ***not*** to be true, so it doesn't make sense to say it's "not yet a fact". The reason The Scientific Method is so useful is because it's the only reliable way of separating ***facts*** from ***intuition, wishful thinking, etc.*** An idea / explanation which isn't "potentially disprovable" is unlikely to be worth thinking about at all.

Comment: Surely anything that is not yet proved to be a fact is potentially disprovable by definition. I don't know of anything that is in the 'not proved as factual, and it has been proved that there will never be a proof' category.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- then you have never heard of [Godel's Incompleteness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel's_incompleteness_theorems)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Without wishing to start an argument, Scientific Method is absolutely not the *only* way of separating facts from intuition etc. Please don't write stuff like that.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I realise there are still people who believe "truth" can be discovered through faith, intuition, religious texts, etc., but such things don't really have much to do with OP's stated context of *not yet a scientifically proven **fact**.* Please don't raise irrelevant objections to the justification I gave for my closevote.

Comment: I'm not talking about faith and intuition. Plenty of fields of study, including reputable academic ones,  discover truth that is in no way amenable to the scientific method. You overstated your case.

Comment: (1) You still haven’t provided an example phrase in which the word you’re asking for would be used. As I understand this community’s rules, this question is therefore not eligible for reopening. (2) You rule out ***hypothesis*** because(?) it refers to “something that is potentially disprovable.” What do you mean? As FF said, if something cannot be disproved, then it is not a candidate fact. (3) Your edit is hard to read. (a) If a sentence is going to contain another sentence, then the inner sentence should be in quotes or otherwise delimited. (b) The double negative hurts my head.

Comment: What about **"maxim"** - *"a short, pithy statement expressing a general truth or rule of conduct."*

Comment: @Scott: (1) Quoted the example phrase. (2) I mean I'm looking for a term for a general truth. Something that doesn't need scientific inquiry, sort of like "the sun rises in the east". (3) Made the edit clearer (I hope) (a) Added quotes, put it in a separate line. (b) No more double negative.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I think you are right. Please add it as an answer! Other words such as "aphorism" or "adage" also seem to fit.

Comment: It's locked so I can't add an answer.  I'll vote to reopen since I think you've addressed the criticisms now.

Comment: *Example*: "Without sufficient proof, this theory is only a **conjecture**". i.e. a proposition (as in mathematics) based on probabilities or apparences before it has been proved or disproved.

Answer (score 11):

**Truism**

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truism):

> A truism is a claim that is so obvious or self-evident as to be hardly worth mentioning, except as a reminder or as a rhetorical or literary device, and is the opposite of falsism.
>   The word may also be used with a different sense in rhetoric, to disguise the fact that a proposition is really just an opinion.
>   *Similarly, stating an accepted truth about life in general can also be called a truism.*

Answer (score 7):

[Axiom](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/axiom): *A statement or proposition that is regarded as being established, accepted, or self-evidently true*

[Merriam/Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/axiom): *a rule or principle that many people accept as true*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom) states: *An axiom or postulate as defined in classic philosophy, is a statement (in mathematics often shown in symbolic form) that is so evident or well-established, that it is accepted without controversy or question.*

Note that this is **not** the pure mathematical definition, which is simply a "given" which may not be true but is assumed true in the current context.

Comment: I'll note that I posted the above answer at a point in time when Brannon Benge had deleted both of his answers which proposed "axiom".  I did this because I felt that "axiom" was a valid answer and needed to be put forward.  Brannon has since undeleted and then redeleted his answers several times, and, at this point of time, at least one is undeleted.  I'm a little confused as to what's going on with regard to his answers and the others referencing them.

Comment: You'll find an explanation on [this meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9367/50044).

Comment: That meta post doesn't explain much.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Theory, either in a colloquial context or scientific. Per wikipedia :

> "A scientific theory is a well-substantiated explanation of some aspect of the natural world that is acquired through the scientific method and repeatedly tested and confirmed, preferably using a written, pre-defined, protocol of observations and experiments. Scientific theories are the most reliable, rigorous, and comprehensive form of scientific knowledge."

Comment: I'm looking for a stronger term. "Theory" and "Hypothesis" are similar. You can take a look at my edit for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll add some rarer words that have similar meanings to the words being mentioned:

  *merriam-webster.com definition:*
  ## [apothegm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apothegm)
  #### *noun* | ap·o·thegm | \ˈa-pə-ˌthem\
  **Definition of APOTHEGM**
  : a short, pithy, and instructive saying or formulation : APHORISM

---

  *oxforddictionaries.com definition:*
  ## [gnome](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gnome#nav2)
  #### *noun* | \ˈnōm\
  **Definition of GNOME**
  : a short statement encapsulating a general truth : MAXIM

Comment: Welcome to our Q&A site. We're a little different from forums with a lot of chatting and commenting. An answer is expected to be a self-contained answer, not a commentary on other posts.  When you have gained enough reputation, just 50, you will gain the privilege of commenting on other people's posts than your own. Until then, please use answers only for your answer, not for commentary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A long-established theory is a scientific law.

A [law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law) can be disproven, but it's been upheld many times up to now.